# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[String : AnyObject]'

Tags: swift, xcode

I keep running into this error. I've tried numerous things, could someone tell me where I've gone wrong at? heres my code:

```
    let receiptFileURL = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL
    let receiptData = try? Data(contentsOf: receiptFileURL!)
    let recieptString = receiptData?.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
    guard let jsonDict: [String: AnyObject] = ["receipt-data" : recieptString! as AnyObject, "password" : IAPProduct.apiID.rawValue as AnyObject] else {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "mainVC", sender: nil)
        }
    }
```

Comment: `["receipt-data" : recieptString! as AnyObject, "password" : IAPProduct.apiID.rawValue as AnyObject]` can't be nil, so it's not an optional, so `guard let` can't be done. Why do you use `guard let` or `if let`? To unwrap an optional, no? Here there is no optional.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are initializing the data, the `["receipt-data" : recieptString! as AnyObject, "password" : IAPProduct.apiID.rawValue as AnyObject]` cannot be nil, and thus it makes no sense to wrap it in `guard`. The only optional you have in this statement is `recieptString`, which you are force-unwrapping (can be causing crash if `recieptString!` is nil.

So change your guard statement to

```
guard let recieptString = receiptData?.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0)) else {
    // ...
    return
}
```

and then initialize the dictionary without guard or force unwrap:

```
let jsonDict: [String: AnyObject] = ["receipt-data" : recieptString as AnyObject, "password" : IAPProduct.apiID.rawValue as AnyObject]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to create a non-optional dictionary so the error

> Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[String : AnyObject]'

reminds you that you cannot optional bind a non-optional type. Remove the `guard` expression.

By the way a JSON collection type does never contain `AnyObject` values, this avoid the ugly bridge cast along the way, and you can omit the `options` parameter in `base64EncodedString`

```
let receiptFileURL = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL!
let receiptData = try! Data(contentsOf: receiptFileURL)
let receiptString = receiptData.base64EncodedString()
let jsonDict : [String: Any] = ["receipt-data" : receiptString, "password" : IAPProduct.apiID.rawValue]
// DispatchQueue.main.async {
//    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "mainVC", sender: nil)
// }
```